# NSwag throws an error when I am trying to map swagger.json to typescript

Tags: npm, swagger, swashbuckle, nswag

I am attempting to use **NSwag** to automate my typescript client code generation. I installed the tool using npm and set up an npm script. This is the script I am running:

```
nswag openapi2tsclient /input:https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json /output:out.ts
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing, but I get an error message which just doesn't make sense to me considering that the uri works (I can download the swagger.json file on my machine).

> NSwag NPM CLI NSwag
>   command line tool for .NET Core NetCore21, toolchain v13.2.3.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.5.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0))
>   Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
>   NSwag bin directory: /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/nswag/bin/binaries/NetCore21
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
>      at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
>   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
>   at NJsonSchema.Infrastructure.DynamicApis.HttpGetAsync(String url)
>   at NSwag.OpenApiDocument.FromUrlAsync(String url) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Core\OpenApiDocument.cs:line 219
>   at NSwag.Commands.OutputCommandBase.ReadSwaggerDocumentAsync(String input) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\OutputCommandBase.cs:line 37
>   at NSwag.Commands.InputOutputCommandBase.GetInputSwaggerDocument() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\InputOutputCommandBase.cs:line 46
>   at NSwag.Commands.CodeGeneration.SwaggerToTypeScriptClientCommand.b__147_0() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\CodeGeneration\OpenApiToTypeScriptClientCommand.cs:line 388   
>   at NSwag.Commands.CodeGeneration.SwaggerToTypeScriptClientCommand.RunAsync() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\CodeGeneration\OpenApiToTypeScriptClientCommand.cs:line 378   
>   at NSwag.Commands.CodeGeneration.SwaggerToTypeScriptClientCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\CodeGeneration\OpenApiToTypeScriptClientCommand.cs:line 371   
>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.Process(String[] args, Object input)
>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.Process(String[] args) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 56 child_process.js:669
>       throw err;

Comment: Can you post your `swagger.json` let's see what's inside... if it's too long or contains copyrighted data please create a minimal that reproduces your issue

Comment: Unfortunately it is way too long and proprietary to post, and creating a minified version would not likely help. Oddly enough, if I download the `swagger.json` and use the folder path to the file instead of a uri, it works. It just seems to fail with a uri.